# Client Component Not re-rendered after pushed with a new query string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a ranking table that shows the fetched data with query string in url. The client component(Rankingtable.js) is not re-rendered by router.push. The client component shows the correct data on refreshing page.
How should I fix this issue?
I am trying to keep the page.js SSR.

page.js

```
export default async function Ranking({ params, searchParams }) {
  return (
    <>
      <RankingTable searchParams={searchParams} />
      <Pagination />
    </>
  );
}
```

RankingTable.js

```
"use client"
export default function RankingTable({ searchParams }) {
  const [rankingData, setRankingData] = useState(null);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(searchParams["page"]);
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));

  let date = searchParams["date"];
  const world_name = searchParams["world_name"];
  const world_type = searchParams["world_type"];
  const className = searchParams["class"];
  const character_name = searchParams["character_name"];

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (character_name) {
        const url = new URL(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST}/api/getRanking/overall`
        );

        const queryParams = {
          date,
          world_name,
          world_type,
          class: className,
          character_name,
          page,
        };

        Object.keys(queryParams).forEach(
          (key) =>
            queryParams[key] !== null &&
            queryParams[key] !== undefined &&
            url.searchParams.append(key, queryParams[key])
        );

        const fetchByCharacterName = await fetch(url.toString());
        const characterRankingData = await fetchByCharacterName.json();
        const characterRanking = characterRankingData.ranking[0].ranking;
        const characterRankingPage = Math.floor(characterRanking / 200 + 1);
        setPage(characterRankingPage);
      }

      const url = new URL(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST}/api/getRanking/overall`
      );

      const queryParams = {
        date,
        world_name,
        world_type,
        class: className,
        page,
      };

      Object.keys(queryParams).forEach(
        (key) =>
          queryParams[key] !== null &&
          queryParams[key] !== undefined &&
          url.searchParams.append(key, queryParams[key])
      );

      const response = await fetch(url.toString());
      const data = await response.json();
      setRankingData(data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [character_name, date, world_name, world_type, className, page]);

  if (!rankingData) {
    return <div>Loading..</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {isMobile ? (
        <MobileTable rankingData={rankingData} characterName={character_name} />
      ) : (
        <PcTable rankingData={rankingData} characterName={character_name} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

pagination.js

```
"use client"
export default function Pagination() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  const page = searchParams.get("page") || 1;

  const createQueryString = useCallback(
    (name, value) => {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
      params.set(name, value);

      return params.toString();
    },
    [searchParams]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={() =>
          router.push(
            pathname + "?" + createQueryString("page", parseInt(page) + 1)
          )
        }
      >
        Next
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: have you tried to use [revalidate path](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath) ?

Comment: @cantdocpp it should be nothing with revalidate since it works on refreshing page

Comment: You need to show where the query params are ultimately read and how. What provides `searchParams` to `<Ranking>`?